# How might I check whether 2 polynomials are congruent modulo (h(x), n)?

Tags: python, primes, sympy

I am currently trying to write my own implementation of the AKS algorithm. The pseudocode for this (taken directly from the paper 'PRIMES is in P') may be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xeTT.png).

The part of this that I am struggling with is the code within the `if` statement on line 5. This requires us to check whether

(x+a)^n = x^n + a  ( mod x^r - 1, n )

Does anyone know how I might do this (in python)? I believe that this congruence is equivalent to saying that there exist polynomials q(x) and r(x) such that

f(x) = g(x) + (x^r - 1) * q(x) + n * r(x)

though I'm not certain of this.

I have attempted to replicate this `if` statement using python and the sympy package with the following code

```
if(sym.div(sym.div(mod_zero, x**r - 1)[1], n)[1] == 0):
     print("Congruent")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interpretation `f(x) = g(x) + (x^r - 1) * q(x) + n * r(x)` is not incorrect, if g is understood to be zero, and q and r have integer coefficients. But it's really two steps: taking the remainder of polynomial division by `(x^r - 1)`, and then applying `mod n` to the coefficients.

In SymPy terms, the comparison is

```
trunc(rem((x + a)**n -(x**n + a), x**r - 1), n) == 0
```

where `rem` find the polynomial remainder, and `trunc` takes coefficients mod n. Examples:

```
x = poly("x")  
n = 35
r = 29
a = 7
trunc(rem((x + a)**n - (x**n + a), x**r - 1), n)
```

outputs `Poly(14*x**25 + 7*x**10 - 7*x**5 + 14*x - 14, x, domain='ZZ')`

while, replacing 35 by 31, we get `Poly(0, x, domain='ZZ')`, which passes the `== 0` test.

#### Speedup

One way to optimize is to also apply `trunc` before `rem`, to make the coefficients smaller prior to division.

```
trunc(rem(trunc((x + a)**n - (x**n + a), n), x**r - 1), n)
```

This helps a bit. But the more substantial speedup can be achieved by using low-level routines from "galoistools" module. They operate with coefficients as lists, like this: `[1, a]` is `x + a`.

```
from sympy.polys.galoistools import gf_lshift, gf_sub, gf_add_ground, gf_pow, gf_rem 
n = 35
r = 29
a = 7
f1 = gf_pow([1, a], n, n, ZZ) # (x + a)**n
f2 = gf_add_ground(gf_lshift([1], n, ZZ), a, n, ZZ) # x**n + a
g = gf_add_ground(gf_lshift([1], r, ZZ), -1, n, ZZ) # x**r - 1
print(gf_rem(gf_sub(f1, f2, n, ZZ), g, n, ZZ))
```

prints `[14, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 28, 0, 0, 0, 14, 21]` which agrees (modulo 35) with the earlier result.

The zero polynomial is `[]` in this representation: so, the test could be as simple as

```
if gf_rem(gf_sub(f1, f2, n, ZZ), g, n, ZZ):
    print("Composite")    # [] is falsy, other lists are truthy
```

The galoistools code is less elegant, but is an order of magnitude faster.